# Tinymce change target path of insert/edit image icon

Tags: image, tinymce

In TyniMce when select the text and right click there is inser/edit Image option is there on click on that how can i open my own aspx page not TynyMce ImageEdit.html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can crete your own contextmenu (and open it on right click) using an own plugin.
The tinymce [contextmenu plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aclass.tinymce.plugins.ContextMenu) should be worth a look at. If you want to develope your own contextmenu plugin have a look at the source code.